# How to define a formula for a steganography message hiding?

Tags: bit-manipulation, xor, steganography

From three pixels I computed their LSB (Least Significant Bit); for example, these are the three consecutive LSB for three pixels: `010`

Then, with the first and second LSB I perform the XOR operation: `1`
The same operation -XOR- for the first and third LSB: `0`

These two binary values -`1` and `0`-, are used to hide a message composed of binary values.

Suppose the three pixels have these three LSB `000` binary values. Then a table is created to hide/insert the two bits:

```
+----------+
|    000   |
+----------+
| 00 | 000 |
+----+-----+
| 01 | 001 |
+----+-----+
| 10 | 010 |
+----+-----+
| 11 | 100 |
+----+-----+
```

When the two bits from the message are `00` none of the three pixels' LSB is changed... but when message bits are `01` the last LSB is changed 00**1**.

Now, suppose that the three pixels have these three LSB `001`, then the table for LSB replacement is:

```
+----------+
|    001   |
+----------+
| 00 | 000 |
+----+-----+
| 01 | 001 |
+----+-----+
| 10 | 101 |
+----+-----+
| 11 | 011 |
+----+-----+
```

I need to do the same for the remaining LSB combinations: `010`, `011`, `100`, `101`, `110`, `111`

I have tried different logical operations to create a table such those two presented.

**Note**: Color version
[image: Table coding]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a triplet of bits, `abc`, can be reduced to a pair of bits, `de`, using a set of specific computations, which are

```
d = a XOR b
e = a XOR c
```

For each `de` pair you're looking to derive the `abc` triplet that is the closest to any triplet of pixels, `ijk`.

### Approach

This is a table of the XOR operations

```
result    from
0         00, 11
1         01, 10
```

The important part here is that you can get the same result from **two** possible combinations, which are **complement to each other**.

In your case you have an independent condition, `a XOR b`, and a dependent one, `a XOR c`, because `a` is used in both of them. `a` (and `b`) can be any of the two values, but `c` has only one option based on what `a` is.

The number of `abc` triplets that reduce to a specific `de` combination can be calculated by using 2 for each independent restriction and 1 for each dependent one and multiplying them together. Therefore, 2 x 1 = 2. And half of these are complement to the other.

A more complicated example would have been `abcde -> fgh`, with

```
f = a XOR b
g = a XOR c
h = d XOR e
```

Since the restrictions are independent, dependent, independent, you get 2 x 1 x 2 = 4 combinations of `abcde` that reduce to the same `fgh`. Again, with half being complement to the other half.

Anyway, for each `de` pair compute the two `abc` triplets that reduce to it and then calculate the [Hamming distance (HD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between each of these triplets and your pixel triplet `ijk`. The result with the lower value is the triplet you'd want to modify your pixels to so that they reduce to that specific `de` pair.

For example, the triplets `000` and `111` reduce to the pair `00`. If the LSBs from your pixels are `000`, `001`, `010` or `100`, you want to modify them to `000`. And if they are `110`, `101`, `011` or `111`, modify them to `111`.

The HD can obviously be a value between 0 and 3. Since the triplets are complement to each other, if the HD between a triplet and your actual pixels is, for example, 1, the HD with the other triplet will be 2, so that both add up to 3. In a similar vein, the table you build for the pixels `000` will be complement to the one for `111`.

```
   | 000 | 111
---+-----+----
00 | 000 | 111
01 | 001 | 110
10 | 010 | 101
11 | 100 | 011
```